# Will Microsoft Edge (Chromium) be able to keep itself up-to-date using limited user accounts

Tags: security, browser, windows-update, microsoft-edge, limited-user-account

Can the [Chromium based rebuild](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13689/microsoft-announces-move-to-chromium-for-the-edge-browser) of [Microsoft's Edge browser](https://www.microsoft.com/edge) continuously and automatically keep itself up to date on limited Windows user accounts, on unmanaged Windows installs? Are any specific Windows Update settings required?

A [long time ago](https://superuser.com/questions/333113/installing-google-chrome-with-system-wide-automatic-updates-on-microsoft-windows), Google Chrome was smartly built to keep itself up-to-date, either on user-specific installs, or system wide, using a background agent. I found this great for basic kiosk use, or getting non-techy people to use limited Windows user accounts, and keeping their most critical application secure, without professional IT patch management.

Now, Microsoft has rebuilt the Edge browser to use Google's Chromium code base, offering performance, usability and privacy enhancements to make a Microsoft product, of all things, a [compelling](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/04/microsoft-edge-is-becoming-the-browser-you-didnt-know-you-needed/) default web browser.

That is, if Edge is able to live up to its potential of delivering automatic, continuous security updates on local Windows accounts without full Administrator privileges. Can anyone confirm if Edge is able to stay current on limited local user accounts, on Home and Pro editions of Windows?

Comment: Yes; It absolutely will.

Comment: Think about it.  The web browser is no different than any other piece of windows.  As long as windows can update itself, the browser can also update itself.